# Converting between different keycodes

Tags: java, converters, lwjgl, keycode

Im currently working on a little game. before you have started the game I have a JFrame where you can setup your controllers. To do this im using the java built-in keylistener and it works great.
The problem occurs when im starting the game and the settings youve made doesn't work.

The game uses the lwjgl api and slick2d api and the keycode for when im checking for buttonpresses is different from the keycodes built in keylistener.

http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/constant-values.html#org.newdawn.slick.Input.KEY_DOWN

A list of the keycodes slick uses. As you can see its different from this list

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

is there a way to convert between these two?

I tried adding a constant but as you probably can see it wont work.

I appreciate every answer :)

Comment: Those are Javascript key codes. Not relevant to Java. The Java event key code constants are encapsulated within the class [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).

Comment: You still have the same problem, converting between potentially different codes. I am just pointing out that you are looking at the wrong list for the Java codes.

Comment: @Radiodef: are you sure about your recommendations? I know that what you say is correct for Swing, but doesn't Slick2D and LWJGL use a different mechanism to trap keystrokes, one that does not involve KeyEvents? I'm asking out of true ignorance because I don't know.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I assume the Slick2D link is correct. The OP's question seems to be that they need to convert from keys obtained from a Swing/AWT key listener to Slick2D codes. I'm saying their Javascript link is wrong for the codes they are obtaining. Maybe I did not fully explain myself.

Comment: If there's no particular pattern to the key mappings, you need a lookup table.

Comment: @user2970531 Note that the best solution here is to not mix GUI tool kits. Unfortunately, I don't know Slick2D to be able to tell you if you can use it to do something similar to what you are doing with the JFrame (pop up a window to obtain the key inputs).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think the best solution will be to remake  the settings tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little solution now. Very simple maybe not the most effiecent but it works. Took some time though

I made a little list that i use for conversion. Could be some bugs but they are pretty easy so fix.

```
backspace               8       14
space           32      57
tab             9       15
enter           13      28
enter2          10      28
shift           16      42
ctrl            17      29
alt             18      56
pause           19      197
caps            20      58
escape          27      1
pgup            33      201
pgdo            34      209
end             35      207
home            36      199
left            37      203
up          38      200
right           39      205
down            40      208
insert2         155     210
delete          127     211
0           48      11
1           49      2
2           50      3
3           51      4
4           5       5
5           53      6
6           54      7
7           55      8
8           56      9
9           57      10
A           65      30
B           66      48
C           67      46
D           68      32
E           69      18
F           70      33
G           71      34
H           72      35
I           73      23
J           74      36
K           75      37
L           76      38
M           77      50
N           78      49
O           79      24
P           80      25
Q           81      16
R           82      19
S           83      31
T           84      20
U           85      22
V           86      47
W           87      17
X           88      45
Y           89      21
Z           90      44
Å           16777413    27
Ä           16777412    40
Ö           16777430    41
LWK             91      219
RWK             92      220
WINDOWS         524     219
SELECT          93      221
NUMPAD0         96      82
NUMPAD1         97      79
NUMPAD2         98      80
NUMPAD3         99      81
NUMPAD4         100     75
NUMPAD5         101     76
NUMPAD6         102     77
NUMPAD7         103     71
NUMPAD8         104     72
NUMPAD9         105     73
MULTIPLY        106     55
ADD             107     78
SUBTRACT        109     74
DECIMAL         110     83
DIVIDE          111     181
F1          112     59
F2          113     60
F3          114     61
F4          115     62
F5          116     63
F6          117     64
F7          118     65
F8          119     66
F9          120     67
F10             121     68
F11             122     87
F12             123     88
F13         124     100
F14         125     101
F15         126     102
NUMLOCK         144     69
SCROLLOCK2      145     70
SEMICOLON       186     39
EQUALSIGN       187     13
COMMA           188     51
COMMA2          44      51
DASH            189     12
PERIOD          190     52
PERIOD2         46      52
FORWARDSLASH        191     53
GRAVE           192     41
OPENBRACKET         219     26
BACKSLASH       220     43
CLOSEBRAKET         221     27
SINGLEQUOTE         222     40
§           16777383    43
LESS            153     -1
DEADACUTE       129     -1
PLUS            521     13
MINUS           45      12
DeadDiaeresis       135     144
```